# Linux cron job file permission

Tags: linux, permissions

I encounter a strange Linux cron job permission error on Amazon Linux and can't found related information on the web.

```
1. First I create a cron job with a regular user
[newuser@node1 home]$ crontab -e
no crontab for newuser - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab

2. Then I try to read the cron job file, permission deny
[newuser@node1 home]$ cat /var/spool/cron/newuser
cat: /var/spool/cron/newuser: Permission denied
```

It is strange as "newuser" is the owner of that file, why "permission denied" ?

```
    Login as root.
    [root@node1 home]# cd /var/spool/cron
    [root@node1 cron]# ls -l

    -rw------- 1 newuser  newuser  47 Aug  3 08:28 newuser

    [root@node1 cron]# cat /var/spool/cron/newuser
    1 1 1 * * /usr/bin/php /tmp/scheduleJob.php

[root@node1 spool]# ll -d /var/spool/cron
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Aug  3 08:28 /var/spool/cron
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux systems to access a file you also need to have access to traverse all the directories in the path (execute bit in UNIX permissions). In your case `/var/spool/cron` permissions are set to `rwx------` and owner is `root`, therefore you cannot traverse into the directory as other user than `root` and get `Permission denied` error when trying to access contents within.

Answer (score 0):

Great Thread, it pointed me in the correct direction.  I was fixing a VM that had been cloned and All the GID and UID's were messed up.

Here is what I did on RedHat 5 to fix mine:

```
[root@pb-qad /]# find . -name cron.allow
./etc/cron.d/cron.allow
--ADDED mfg user

[root@pb-qad ~]# chown root:crontab /usr/bin/crontab
chown: `root:crontab': invalid group

[root@pb-qad ~]# groupadd crontab
[root@pb-qad ~]# groupmod crontab --gid 65535

[root@pb-qad ~]# chown root:crontab /usr/bin/crontab
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root

[root@pb-qad ~]# chmod g+s /usr/bin/crontab
[root@pb-qad ~]# ls -al /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 315432 Dec 11  2009 /usr/bin/crontab

[root@pb-qad ~]# usermod -a -G crontab mfg
[root@pb-qad ~]# groupmod -g 65535 crontab
groupmod: 65535 is not a unique GID

[root@pb-qad ~]# cd /var/spool/
```

#### FINAL FIX

```
[root@pb-qad spool]# chown root:crontab cron
[root@pb-qad spool]# ll -al
total 476
drwxr-xr-x 16 root   root      4096 Oct  1  2009 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root   root      4096 Mar 21 15:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Dec  5  2008 anacron
drwx------  3 daemon qad       4096 Nov 16  2009 at
drwxrwxrwx  2 smmsp  smmsp    69632 Apr 25 09:25 clientmqueue
drwx-wx--T  2 root   crontab   4096 Mar 21 15:49 cron
```

Now, Cron works as mfg user!